# Android dialog orienation issue

Tags: android, dialog, screen-orientation

I used a customized dialog to show the face-book login page. I used a webview inside a linear layout to show the login page. It works fine. But when the orientation changes it doesn't fit to screen size. I need to have dialog box which resize with orientation. please help me with some sample code.

```
public FbDialog(Context context, String url, DialogListener listener) {

    super(context);

    mUrl = url;

    mListener = listener;

}



@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");



    mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    setUpTitle();

    setUpWebView();

    Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    final float scale =

        getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    int orientation =

        getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    float[] dimensions =

        (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)

                ? DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE : DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT;

    addContentView(mContent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(

            display.getWidth() - ((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f)),

            display.getHeight() - ((int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f))));

}



private void setUpTitle() {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//    Drawable icon = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.facebook_icon);

    mTitle = new TextView(getContext());

    mTitle.setText("Facebook");

    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    mTitle.setBackgroundColor(FB_BLUE);

    mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);

    mTitle.setCompoundDrawablePadding(MARGIN + PADDING);

//    mTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);

    mContent.addView(mTitle);

}



private void setUpWebView() {

    mWebView = new WebView(getContext());

    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FbDialog.FbWebViewClient());

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);

    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);

    mContent.addView(mWebView);

}
```

Comment: Are we God? That without seeing any code, we know where is the problem

Comment: Hi. I have the same problem! Did you managed to find the fix to this bug ? I think the @xjaphx answer refers when you declare the Facebook webview inside a layout, but as I could see on the code above the webview is created inside of `FbDialog` class, like in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have created the dialog layout using xml, you can create another xml for landscape layout and place it inside layout-land folder. This way this xml will be loaded when the orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in create two more folder:

```
/res/layout-port
/res/layout-land
```

Create two according-layout XMLs and put into those 2 folders. The corresponding layout will be inflated if orientation changes.

Comment: Hi. I think @Unnikrishnan PV has declared the webview inside of FbDialog class. Do you know a solution in this case? I just don't know how to fix this... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you cant detect the orientation change in a Dialog as there is no OnConfigurationChanged().

So when you rotate the screen from Portrait to Landscape is chops off the bottom of the dialog and you cant scroll down.

The simplest solution I found was to add vertical scrollbars to the webView and then during onCreate(), calculate the smallest value of width and height and use this value for both width and height. This creates a square dialog which will fit in both portrait and landscape views without having to worry about resizing. Its not a great solution, but it works...

```
    int height = display.getHeight();
    int width  = display.getWidth();
    int size = height > width ? width : height;

    addContentView(mContent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size - 10, size - 10));
```